# iPhone copy file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I create two file paths with this code:

```
NSString *fileName = [[self genRandStringLength:15] stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];
NSString *finalFilePath = [self.videoFiles stringByAppendingString:fileName];

NSString *tmpFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp.mp4"]];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tmpFile error:NULL];
```

Then i have some code to create video file and the i want to save it in the Document Folder:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:tmpFile toPath:finalFilePath error:&err];
```

And i get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “temp.mp4” doesn’t exist." 
UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E5B7BBCB-311F-41A3-949D-8A309F535C95/tmp/temp.mp4, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
    ), NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E5B7BBCB-311F-41A3-949D-8A309F535C95/Documents/VideoFiles/0iWDmhLvbbzM6SE.mp4, NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E5B7BBCB-311F-41A3-949D-8A309F535C95/tmp/temp.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x12f0099b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Just for some checking i try to copy the video to the iPhone Photo library with :
`UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tmpFile, self, nil, nil);`

And it's work fine, so the file is exist.

Comment: What is the value of `finalFilePath`?

Comment: Check the folder mentioned on disk in the simulator. The file will not be there, so you probably removed it before or created it somewhere else.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam This is the value `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4D550508-ACEC-427E-A6FA-B10C7323CF43/Documents/VideoFiles/0MiJlwTi7rlDi4g.mp4`

Comment: Don't forget that you need to create any needed subfolders before you can use them.

Comment: You delete file (removeItemAtPath) and copy it after deletion? Isn't that why you get the error. Maybe I overlooked something. You are getting this issue that the source file doesn't exist. Add breakpoint and in lldb verify (using filemanager API) that the file is in tmp dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
NSString *fileName = [[self genRandStringLength:15] stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];
NSString *finalFilePath = [self.videoFiles stringByAppendingString:fileName];

NSString *tmpFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp.mp4"]];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:tmpFile];

if (success)
{
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:tmpFile toPath:finalFilePath error:&err];

  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tmpFile error:NULL];

}
```